# JavaFX 2 objects containing textField never cleared by garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, javafx-2

Has anyone else come across this? This happens when:

- Object A contains textField (or textArea) B.
- I have used B.setOnKeyPressed in A's constructor to do stuff when a key is pressed in B.
- Afterward, when A has completed its function and goes out of scope, the garbage collector won't remove it.

This does not happen if A does not contain B, or if I have not used B.setOnKeyPressed, or if B never receives focus. This results in a memory leak when a lot of objects of A's class need to be used and then discarded (only they do not get discarded!)

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure without code but it seems to be correct behavior.

You have `TextField` `B` on the scene. In `A`'s constructor you create anonymous class, let's name it `A$onKeyPressed`. Anonymous classes in Java are not static, so this one keeps reference to `A` object.

After contstructor done you have link

```
scene -> B -> onKeyPressedListeners -> A$onKeyPressed -> A
```

Thus A is not valid for GC.

To avoid this you can make named static inner class and use in the constructor instead. E.g.:

```
public class A {
    public A(TextField B) {
        B.setOnKeyPressed(new AHandler());
    }

    private static class AHandler implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {  /* doStuff */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sergey, thank you very much for your answer. However, this does not seem to solve the problem. The memory leak persists even with a static Handler. Also, (do stuff) then also needs to be static, which is not desirable in my application. However, I did find a way around it, which I am posting as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did find a way around this, by doing two things:

1. removing the listener when A goes out of scope, by: B.setOnKeyPressed(null);
2. remove B from its parent node C, by C.getChildren().remove(B);

This allows A to be reclaimed by the garbage collector. Note that (1) or (2) alone do not work, though. Both had to be used.